# Prove that $S_5$ has no elements of order $120$.

Tags: group-theory

Prove that $S_5$ has no elements of order $120$.

I know that by Lagrange's theorem, elements can have order $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120$.

I feel like I need to use some sort of contradiction argument here but I'm not sure where to go with that. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it had an element of order $120$ it would be cyclic (hence abelian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_{5}$ has order $120$. If there was an element of order $120$ in $S_{5}$, it would mean $S_{5}$ is a cyclic group. Is $S_{5}$ cyclic?